# Slir (Image manipulator) not working on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I just upload my contents to my new website (server) and noticed that Slir stopped working. I read a few forum boards and noticed it could be a path issue.

Does anyone know exactly what needs to be edited or changed for Slir to work?

My Home Directory is `/home/username/public_html`

I used that path in the `slir.configuration`, however it still didnt work. I received a `Page Not Found`.

I am also using codeigniter and php for reference.

Localhost slir worked fine without any configurations needed.

On some of the blogs I read that slir may be having trouble with the `.htaccess`, but I'm not that familiar with that to change it.

```
# Prevent other scripts from interfering with SLIR
php_value auto_prepend_file none
php_value auto_append_file none

# Pretty URLs
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=40]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Prevent viewing of the error log file in its default location
<Files slir-error-log>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
</Files>
```

***MORE INFO***

I just spoke to the web hosting IT department and they mentioned that only one `.htaccess` is accessible at a time. He had to close down the root `.htaccess` to use the `slir .htaccess`.

How can I fix this issue on my VPS server?

Answer (score 0):

Issue Fixed!

**FIXED**

Just comment out the top 2 items and it worked! on the `slir .htaccess`

```
# Prevent other scripts from interfering with SLIR
#php_value auto_prepend_file none
#php_value auto_append_file none

# Pretty URLs
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=40]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Prevent viewing of the error log file in its default location
<Files slir-error-log>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
</Files>
```

Comment: I think that `[S=40]` is unsuitable. There as written it could take effect with `[S=1]`. [Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s).

Comment: @Tpojka - Im sure when the person who made `slir` was thinking that some may end up putting more >= 40 different `-` so it is suitable. Take a look https://github.com/rezozero/slir

Comment: From code in github repository AFAIK it is not well. I don't say it won't work that way, just saying that skipping of 40 rules is pointless if only 1 rule is coming.